# C# wrapper for acdbEntGet and acdbEntGetX

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, autocad, objectarx

I need a wrapper for acdbEntGet and acdbEntGetX in C#. These functions are located in accore.dll (AutoCAD 2014) and I've tried this:

```
[DllImport("accore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "acdbEntGetX")]
public static extern IntPtr acdbEntGetX(Int64 e, IntPtr app);

[DllImport("accore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "acdbEntGet")]
public static extern IntPtr acdbEntGet(Int64 e);
```

The return value (a IntPtr) is always 0 from both functions. No errors or exceptions.

Almost every ObjectARX C++ functions are wrapped in the C# managed libraries, but those two functions are not. I wonder why.

Oh, and someone may ask why I need those functions... The answer is that I would like to return a list to Lisp which can be given directly to `(entmake)` without modifications. That's done with acdbEntGet and acdbEntGetX. Creating the list "by hand" is an option, but that's not what I want (and yes, I know how to create lists in C# ObjectARX) :)

Edit: Here is how these functions are defined in C++

```
struct resbuf *acdbEntGetX (const ads_name ent, const struct resbuf *args);
struct resbuf *acdbEntGet (const ads_name ent);
```

`struct resbuf` is a linked list defined in adsdef.h

```
struct resbuf {                                                  
        struct resbuf *rbnext; 
        short restype;
        union ads_u_val resval;
};
```

`ads_name` is an array of two 64-bits integers (if I remember correct)

Comment: Can you post the C header definition?

Comment: Ok, question edited.

Comment: Can't really say as I dont have AutoCAD, but if the function is returning a struct, do you need to follow the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779444/p-invoke-c-function-that-returns-pointer-to-a-struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my edit of Maxences answer was rejected, I’ll rewrite the correct solution here. I've also included the code for acdbEntGetX

```
[DllImport("accore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr acdbEntGet(AdsName objName);

[DllImport("accore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr acdbEntGetX(AdsName objName, IntPtr app);

[DllImport("acdb19.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?acdbGetAdsName@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@AEAY01_JVAcDbObjectId@@@Z")]
static extern ErrorStatus acdbGetAdsName64(out AdsName objName, ObjectId id);
```

Example:

```
ResultBuffer app = new ResultBuffer();
app.Add(new TypedValue((int)LispDataType.Text, "*"));

AdsName name = new AdsName();
acdbGetAdsName64(out name, o);

IntPtr res = acdbEntGetX(name, app.UnmanagedObject);
ResultBuffer rb;
if (res != IntPtr.Zero) rb = ResultBuffer.Create(res, true);
```

There is no need for the struct ads_name as it is in the assembly acdbmgd.dll (AdsName)

Answer (score 2):

For `entget`, it should be something like this:

```
public struct ads_name
{
    public IntPtr a;
    public IntPtr b;
};

[DllImport("accore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl]
static extern IntPtr acdbEntGet(ads_name objName);
```

Use it like this:

```
IntPtr res = acdbEntGet(name);
if (res != IntPtr.Zero)
  ResultBuffer rb = ResultBuffer.Create(res, true);
```

To convert an ObjectId to an ads_name, you have to use `acdbGetAdsName`:

```
[DllImport("acdb19.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="?acdbGetAdsName@@YA?AW4ErrorStatus@Acad@@AEAY01_JVAcDbObjectId@@@Z"]
static extern ErrorStatus acdbGetAdsName64(ads_name objName, ObjectId id);
```

In [this post](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/unnamed-ucs/td-p/4345297/page/2), you can find full code in VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks, Maxence. After corrected your code (and edited your answer), it worked.

Comment: First argument of acdbGetAdsName64 needs to be an out reference. Declaraton of ResultBuffer cannot be done in the "then" statement.

Comment: Hmm... Seems like my edit was rejected (?!). Anyway... Thanks. And for those of you who cannot compile Maxences code: See comment above.