# C# wrapper (pinvoke) for Debian apt library libapt-pkg

Tags: c#, .net, linux, pinvoke, apt

I need to retrieve package information in my C# application running on Linux.
I've tried to use [Python.NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/README.rst) which wrap [python-apt](https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/index.html) which wrap `libapt-pkg.so`, and it works but I would prefer to go more direct by pinvoke libapt-pkg.

But I need help on my DLLImport statement.

When using python-apt I first initialize the `apt` module, then instantiat the `Cache()` class and then called the `Cache.keys()` function which retrieve all package-names as a string array.

If I can get this to work using pinvoke I believe I have a good chance getting the rest working too (retrieve the more advanced stuff)

Just to show some code which doesn't work, but just to get started:

```
[DllImport("libapt-pkg")]
public static extern dynamic GetPkgCache();

dynamic AptCache = GetPkgCache();
```

I get the error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: 'Cannot
> marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination
> (Marshaling to and from COM VARIANTs isn't supported).'

I've been looking in the header file [cachefile.h](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/main/apt-pkg/cachefile.h) of the apt project. Maybe these lines are useable for my DllImport statement?

```
..
inline operator pkgCache &() const {return *Cache;};
inline operator pkgCache *() const {return Cache;};
..
inline pkgCache* GetPkgCache() { BuildCaches(NULL, false); return Cache; };
..
```

But I'm new to C/C++ so it doesn't make much sense for me at present.

UPDATE:

Thanks for the feedback.

```
[DllImport("libapt-pkg")]
public static extern IntPtr GetPkgCache();
```

Now I get the error

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point
> named 'GetPkgCache' in shared library 'libapt-pkg'.'

Comment: You should delete the duplicate question on U&L, this is the correct place to post it... Anyway, I don't see an overload for `GetPkgCache` that accepts a parameter.

Comment: I don't think that `dynamic` is correct return type here, Try to change it to `IntPtr` and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` or something similar to get instance. See here for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779444/p-invoke-c-function-that-returns-pointer-to-a-struct

Comment: @Serg I think you're right. I would have expected it to simply return the pointer value, but I tested it in one of my projects and `extern dynamic` doesn't seem to work, even in the simplest case, where the method is returning an `int` primitive. In .NET 4.7.2 on Windows 10, the error is `MarshalDirectiveException: 'PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants.'`.

Comment: @MrCalvin, After update this looks like that desired function is not exportable at all (i.e. does not included in the export table), but I'm unsure. I'm afraid,  further investigation will need more deep knowledge about apt-pkg internals, what I don't have. Sorry.

Comment: I don't even know if it's the right function, nor if it is a function at all. I don't know how a function is defined in a c/cc+ header file. I'm on deep water, I know :-P